# Error with Plone 4.1 adding package that uses plone.app.dexterity

Tags: plone, zope, dexterity, plone-4.x

I created a product that uses `plone.app.dexterity` and I needed modify the buildout.cfg file to include these dependencies:

```
plone.app.dexterity = 1.2.1
five.intid = 1.0
plone.app.intid = 1.0
plone.supermodel = 1.1
plone.autoform = 1.2
```

The buildout executed perfectly, but when I try to run the Plone instance I received these messages:

```
"/usr/local/pl4/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.dexterity-2.2.3-py2.6.egg/plone/dexterity/content.py", line 183, in <module>
class DexterityContent(DAVResourceMixin, PortalContent, PropertyManager, Contained):
File "/usr/local/pl4/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.dexterity-2.2.3-py2.6.egg/plone/dexterity/content.py", line 284, in DexterityContent
@security.private
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/pl4/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 12.2-12.39
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/pl4/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.1-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/meta.zcml", line 43.4-47.10
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/pl4/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/plone/app/dexterity/meta.zcml", line 4.2-4.67
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/pl4/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.directives.dexterity-1.0.2-py2.6.egg/plone/directives/dexterity/meta.zcml", line 10.4-10.36
AttributeError: private
```

I'm using plone 4.1.

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dexterity was still an optional add on for Plone 4.1, and it only worked with a carefully defined known-good set of components.

To include the known-good set in your buildout, add to your buildout:

```
extends =
    [existing extends ...]
    http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.2.1?plone=4.1
```

Make sure the good-py KGS is the last of your extends.
If you want it to work offline, download from the URL and specify the downloaded file
in the extends section.